# Mongo Shell compatibility

Tags: mongodb, compatibility

Is there any policy regarding having `mongo` binary of a specific version connecting to another version of MongoDB server?

I am implementing a broker to submit Javascript scripts to different MongoDB clusters on different versions.

Should I equip my broker with different versions of the `mongo` binary?
Or I can assume the last version of the binary will be backward compatible?

Comment: While you can pass scripts via the command-line, the `mongo` shell is primarily intended to be an interactive admin tool paired with the same major version of the MongoDB server. Successive major releases of the `mongo` shell include backward compatibility where possible, but you're likely to run into differences across a wider range of MongoDB server releases. If you are building a tool it would be much more robust to build on a supported MongoDB driver API which includes proper I/O and error handling. Are there specific reasons you want to use the `mongo` shell?

Comment: @Stennie I would use the mongo shell mainly because you can submit javascript files to submit changes (so you have some scripting features a la PL-SQL). See it like a tool for submitting changes to MongoDb.